# how to implement TextWatcher when my Json is ready?

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in Android development, and currently I am facing problem with my project, I want to connect my app to local host, I have seen the ways to do that and picked up the simplest one using json, thus I stopped on the way of implementing my `TextWatcher` adding it in to that code. The rest of the things I have done as it requires on steps.

Please take a look at my code and tell me what is my mistake?

this is my Java code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
HttpClient httpClient;
private HttpPost mhttpPost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String[] mobileArray = {"Laptops","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,mobileArray);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    mhttpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.1/index/get_for_mobile");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(mhttpPost);
        HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
    catch (Exception e ){}

}
private TextWatcher search = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

}

and here is my xml code:

```
<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"

        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="399dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: the edited code didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

you have not added textwatcher to EditText or any View ,of which text event you want handle .see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
Why you need to implement textwacther whicile ending json to localhost .

Comment: I need to add TextWatcher to implement my SearchView cause when I am typing my ip to connect to localhost it doesnt proceed further

Comment: try adding done button yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);or android:imeOptions="actionDone"                 instead of text watcher and on click of done button add code to call post request